# window.setTimeout for processing async calls synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronization, settimeout

I'm working on a Google Maps API functionality that incorporates getting the elevation at some point of a directions result. This is fine for smaller routes, but larger routes with more paths become a problem. So I've splitted the total path into separate batches to execute but sometimes they return in a random order. This is caused by the fact that the Google Elevation Service is called asynchronously (and there's no other way).

The desired result is to output the elevation data when all batches have completed (even if it's just one batch). So I figured to incorporate window.setTimeout to process the calls in order but I'm wondering two things:

1. Is this a good way, or is there a better alternative?
2. I'm wrapping and wrapping functionality but end up with nothing good. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction? Below is my pseudo approach.

   function getElevationData() {
     var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();
     var batchSize = 250;
     var elevationBatches = Math.ceil(directions.routes[0].overview_path / batchSize);

   for(var i = 0; i < elevationBatches; i++) {
       var thisBatch = [];

   ```
   for(var = j = i * batchSize; j < i * batchSize + batchSize; j++) {
     if(j < directions.routes[0].overview_path.length) {
       thisBatch.push(directions.routes[0].overview_path[j]);
     } else { 
       break;
     }
   }

   getElevationBatchData(elevator, i, batchData);
   ```

   }
   }

   function getElevationBatchData(elevator, batch, data) {
     window.setTimeout(function() {
       // something with checking if it has completed..? refiring this function again if not?

   ```
   elevator.getElevationAlongPath({
     path: data,
     samples: 256
   }, function(elevations, status) {
     // process the result (basically checking for status OK, concatenating and adding rows to the DataTable
   }
   ```

   }, 100);
   }

Sorry for the code markup, somehow; when I type more pseudo code in SO's editor won't apply correct code formatting anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just run all requests in parallel (i.e. using your setTimeout approach, but it is very likely not even necessary here) and then display overall results when all of those requests complete and return partial result?

```
 function onRequestComplete(index, context) {
    alreadyProcessed++;
    if (alreadyProcessed == totalNumOfRequests) {
        showResults();
    }
    batches[index].data = context;
 }

 function doAsyncRequest(index) {
    someObject.doAsyncRequest(batches[index], function (err, data) {
        onRequestComplete(index, data);
    });
 }

 for(var i=0;i<totalNumOfRequests;i++){
     doAsyncRequest(i);
 };
```

Comment: I like the simplicity in this. I see the concept and work this out. This will do fine for as far as I can see. Thanks! +1A